# How can I tell poedit to ignore Non-ASCII text errors?

Tags: php, poedit

I am trying to have poedit create a catalog on my PHP project.
It crashes on a Non-ASCII character in some of my files.

Since the project is quite big, I was wondering if it was possible to run poedit and ignore these errors rather than ignore each file where they appear.

I am using the poedit GUI on Windows.
I am trying to localize French content into English and vice versa.

Comment: Investigating the other solution of using the Characterset conversion tool. That seems to be a cleaner approach.

Comment: That doesn't answer your question, but in general it is best to use english as the reference language and translate to other languages (French in your case) from it. Two reasons: gettext tools assume you are doing so (and thus expect ASCII) and if you want to translate to some other language it will usually be easier to find a translator (not always though). I often use english->english translation too (so the strings are not hardcoded).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In poEdit, go to Catalog and Settings and check the properties in the Source Code charset. Try with UTF-8. (tip is worked for me and is from http://www.netvivs.com/error-xgettext-non-ascii-string-in-poedit/)

Comment: Mine path was: Catalogue > Properties... > In Translation properties Tab > Source code charset: